# Why Qiling doesn't recognize the right EntryPoint?

Tags: ida, gdb, emulation, uefi

I'm trying to emulate an EFI driver. Luckily, I found a nice emulator called **Qiling** and try to debug it with **GDB** but it doesn't recognize the right Entry-Point.

Here is the Entry-Point in IDA and in GDB with Qiling.

How to resolve this problem and why does it happen?
[image]

[image]